# Inserting .png files from a folder into PowerPoint with a Labeled Object

Tags: excel, vba, image, insert, powerpoint

I had a question earlier about how to import data into PowerPoint using PowerPoint VBA and ended up finding a solution from Excel VBA. That being said I haven't found a solution that works for Excel because it gives me errors despite copying and pasting the exact code.

```
strPic ="Picture Name"
Set shp = ws.Shapes(strPic)

'Capture properties of exisitng picture such as location and size
With shp
    t = .Top
    l = .Left
    h = .Height
    w = .Width
End With

ws.Shapes(strPic).Delete

Set shp = ws.Shapes.AddPicture("Y:\our\Picture\Path\And\File.Name", msoFalse, msoTrue, l, t, w, h)
shp.Name = strPic
shp.ScaleHeight Factor:=1, RelativeToOriginalSize:=msoTrue
shp.ScaleWidth Factor:=1, RelativeToOriginalSize:=msoTrue
```

This did **NOT** work for me because it said the method is not found.

The solution I am looking for can be on either PowerPoint VBA or Excel VBA, I am not picky. Even if it is 1 line of code that does it one time, and doesn't use fancy looping I am ok with that as well because I would rather iterate 100 lines of code and change the slide number than beat my head against the wall trying to find answers to this issue!

TL:DR

VBA Code in Excel **or** PowerPoint that will allow me to select a named shape in a PowerPoint Slide and then insert a .png image from a folder.

Literally I want this line of code to work, but it doesn't

`Set shp = ws.Shapes("Named Shape").AddPicture("Y:\our\Picture\Path\And\File.Name", msoFalse, msoTrue, l, t, w, h)`

I have tried this For Excel VBA:

`oPPTFile.Slides(100).Shapes("Name").Fill.UserPicture("D:\Pictures\Picture.png")`

but it didn't work even though that was the exact same code style I used to replace text in differently named shapes...

`oPPTFile.Slides(100).Shapes("Different Name").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Some Text"`

Maybe instead of oPPTFile it's something else and oPPTFile is meant for text? I don't know, this is where I am stuck!!!

Answer (score 0):

I finally found my answer:

```
Sub main()
Dim objPresentaion As Presentation
Dim objSlide As Slide
Dim objImageBox As Shape

Set objPresentaion = ActivePresentation
Set objSlide = objPresentaion.Slides.Item(1)
Set objImageBox = objSlide.Shapes.AddPicture("D:\Folder\Picture.png", msoCTrue, msoCTrue, 100, 100)

End Sub
```

The 100, 100 as near as I can tell ensures that whatever picture you import to the slide object fills the entire object. Key take aways: The shape has to be able to recieve images, and it has to be present on the slide already. Beyond that Item(#) refers to the Slide #, not the shape #. If I am wrong as to why this code works the way it does please correct me, but I have seen a LOT of questions about this subject and very few answers that were straightforward.

Now that being said this is NOT a loop, and I have no idea how to make this a loop process. You can iterate those Set lines as often as you like and it WILL work pretty quickly as well. 100 images maybe took a minute, probably less.

So hopefully this helps someone in the future!

Comment: The 100, 100 tells PPT to import the picture at 100 points high by 100 points wide; unless you're inserting square pictures, this will distort the image; instead you can use -1, -1 to have PPT insert the picture at "natural" size (undistorted). And the AddPicture command adds a new picture shape; it doesn't insert the picture into an existing shape, so you don't need an existing shape there to start with.

Comment: I had to post another answer in order to properly respond to your comment. Thank you for the heads up about the -1, -1! Actually how would I rewrite the line so that I just use the .AddPicture command because deleting the previous text doesn't do it. I understand nothing about the syntax involved...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that explains the problem I am having. I have the shape in the exact place I want the picture to show up. That being said, when it imports, and it does import correctly, when I try to use

```
With shp.Fill.PictureEffects
    Dim eff As PictureEffect
    Set eff = .Insert(msoEffectSharpenSoften)
    eff.EffectParameters(1).Value = 1
End With
```

Only some of the pictures work???

Comment: What's different between the pictures that do and don't work?

Comment: I honestly couldn't begin to guess. As I said in my other post, the issue seems to be reading what is INSIDE the object, and the making sure it is a .jpeg file. This is an issue because .jpeg doesn't typically save as transparent backgrounds, and simply changing the file type to .jpeg from .png may end up resulting in corruption of some sort, nevermind the extra step I have to take to do so.

I render the images using the same software, and more or less the same settings except for dimensions, and then save as .png. All of my images are essentially the same format.

Comment: >> and simply changing the file type to .jpeg from .png may end up resulting in corruption  <<  WILL end up corrupting the file, if you mean just renaming the file with a different extension. That's like putting a "SUGAR" label on the salt container. It's not going to end well for the coffee.  ;-)  Anyhow, can you post examples of PNG files that do and don't work?

Comment: It was false hope on my end, neither PNG's nor JPEGS worked, regardless of whether or not they were added through automation

Comment: It's kind of unclear what is and what isn't working. ARE you able to insert images the way you want to, and it's just the adjustments that aren't working?  Suggestion:  start a new question here, with JUST the current problem.

Comment: The issue is the adjustments aren't working, the importing works just fine.

Comment: OK, let's have you create a folder on Dropbox/OneDrive/Whatever, add an example presentation that includes one or two of these pictures AND the original picture files, separate from the presentation.  Share the folder and post the link to it here.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ijtlpv7kst6lxwr/AABiWDXOT38bbUUTJYEma-fta?dl=0 Let me know if this works. I have since converted all of my images manually, saved them manually as PNG's and just ran the macro to upload images to specific shapes. However, if you can figure this out so I don't have to do that anymore I will be incredibly grateful!

Comment: Thanks. Right off, I can tell you that your JPG file is actually a PNG file with an incorrect extension. As I mentioned earlier, giving a file a different extension won't convert it; it'll only confuse everything.  If you  open the file in an editor like Notepad++ (free), you'll see that the first characters in your "JPG" file are "%PNG" ... it's a PNG file already. All you need to do is rename it to give it a PNG extension.

Comment: Sure, but regardless of how I saved the file types, it didn't work because PNG isn't apparently recognized as the MsoPIctureType??? That is the underlying issue I am trying to fix.

Comment: Both pictures are in placeholders, so PPT treats them as Type 14, msoPlaceholder.  See the new code I've added in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead of the existing code in your example file. I changed the Value to -9 to make it more obvious; you can change that back to whatever you want. This now works with both pictures and pictures in placeholders.

```
Sub EsoteraCardInitialFormatting()

    Dim currentSlide As Slide
    Dim shp As Shape
    Dim eff As PictureEffect
     
    For Each currentSlide In ActivePresentation.Slides
        
        For Each shp In currentSlide.Shapes
            Select Case shp.Type
                Case msoPicture
                    With shp.Fill.PictureEffects
                      Set eff = .Insert(msoEffectSharpenSoften)
                      eff.EffectParameters(1).Value = -9
                    End With
                Case msoPlaceholder
                    If shp.PlaceholderFormat.ContainedType = msoPicture Then
                    With shp.Fill.PictureEffects
                      Set eff = .Insert(msoEffectSharpenSoften)
                      eff.EffectParameters(1).Value = -9
                    End With
                    End If
            End Select
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I copy and pasted the above code, and still recieved the error message. I took a screenshot of the error and placed it in the Dropbox. I have never used Case before in VBA, and it looks like it should work, but the error flagged at the first Case block of code. Is it because I am using PPT 2013? Should that even matter?

Comment: Exactly what line triggered the error and were you running the code on the same presentation as you uploaded to dropbox, ie, the one that I also have?  It's been a while since I used PPT 2013; I don't *think* it'd matter, but I'll give it a try when I'm at a computer with 2013 on it. That may take a while.

Comment: Yes it was, and it was line: 13. For the record the only difference between the version I put in the Drop Box and the one I am trying to work with is the number of slides. The pictures were processed the same way, and I deleted all of the "JPEG" photos from my drive. So what you have to work with is exactly what I am working with but with around 100 slides instead of just 2.

Comment: Line 13 being this?  Set eff = .Insert(msoEffectSharpenSoften)

Comment: I've tested your presentation in PPT 2013; using the most recent version of code that I posted. It works w/o error, so I'm not sure what the problem might be at your end.  Have you made sure that your copy of PPT is fully updated?  Early releases of 2013 were unacceptably buggy.

Comment: well, my version is the version I got from the military when I was enlisted back then... so you may very well be correct. If that is the case I will double check to see if it can even BE updated! However, it is very reassuring that this Macro works as intended. I just hope I don't have to buy a new version of Office just to use it haha

Comment: It looks like SP1 is still available.  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/technical-details-about-service-pack-1-sp1-for-microsoft-office-2013-and-related-desktop-products-442763a2-4ef4-3e88-a2eb-ae1a0d1629b1

Comment: Apparently I already had that upgrade. Well, for now it seems I am at a point of blockage haha. Thank you immensely for your help! At the very least this should help someone else down the road!

Comment: Seems so ... sorry.  All I can tell you is that it really does work as expected here in 2013 and later versions.